# Split gem dashboard actions don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ab-testing

When trying to reset experiments in the Split gem for a/b testing, I keep getting server errors:

```
NoMethodError at /_split/reset/listing_headline
undefined method `reset' for nil:NilClass
file: dashboard.rb location: block in <class:Dashboard> line: 31
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not in your case, but I've seen this when someone was using symbols as test names instead of strings.

example: don't use:

:myTest => {}

use:

```
"myTest" => {
  :alternatives => [
    { :name => 'default', :percent => 50 },
    { :name => 'alt', :percent => 50 },
  ],
  :resettable => false
  :metric => :lead,
}
```